# OpenCV3.0: distributing each process on different core for faster processing.

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

Aim of my project is to optimize my OpenCV programs to make use of all the cores available on the processor. 
I am working with Core-i3 and 2 quad core ARM boards to benchmark the performances of various OpenCV applications. I am pretty new to some strategies like Multithreading etc.

Here is a small sample code for line detection:

```
void line_detect::detect(UMat & src)
{

Mat threshold, HSV;
cvtColor(src, HSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

inRange(HSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), threshold);

erode(threshold, threshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(6, 6)));
dilate(threshold, threshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3)));

vector<Vec4i> lines;

HoughLinesP(threshold, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 50, 10);
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line(src, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
}

imshow("Threshold", threshold);

imshow("Lines detected", src);

cvWaitKey(30);
}
```

How can i run functions like cvtColor and inRange on 2 different cores to parallelize this code? How can i check different core performance in real time?

OS - Win 10
IDE - Visual studio 2015

Comment: why was it down voted?

Comment: Do you know how to run any random function in a separate thread? If yes, what makes this case special? Read a thread tutorial first, then you'll be able to ask useful followup questions.

Comment: Well. Yes i know basics of threading. But multi threading doesn't mean running processes on different cores. Multi threading can be done on single core as well. multiple threading and multiprocessing are quite different concepts. My above question is about multi processing.

Comment: 1) you code is sequential code, since you need that `cvtColor` finishes before running `inRange`. So you can't actually parallelize this snippet. 2) this code should be really fast (except maybe for Hough), so it'll be probably slower to start new processes/threads and move computation.

Comment: Multiprocessing doesn't mean running processes on different cores either and you can make use of multiple cores with multithreading, so no, you don't know the basics of threading yet. It's exactly this thing that a downvote requires, the mousover has this text: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make parallel algorithms such as `cvtColor` and `erode`/`dilate`. It has already paralleled internally and provide maximum performance on supported platforms.

You just need to build OpenCV with some parallel backend. On Windows it may be Concurrency, TBB, OpenMP, etc. Just make sure that one of this option is enabled in cmake log.

For example:

```
...    
Parallel framework:            Concurrency
...
```

Instruction how to build OpenCV you may find [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

In most cases, if you parallelize such algorithms "outside" the function you don't get performance benefits.

Comment: i have compiled OpenCV with OpenMP and OpenCL enabled. i agree with you but can i see real time core performance on Windows?